# Trying to create a Conditional Formatting rule. Having some Issues

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I need the rule to display the dates in Column AA in red text IF the dates are BEFORE today AND if the status is NOT "Delivered".

Here is what I have:

```
=IF(AND($AA2<(TODAY()),X2<>"Delivered"),TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit surprised what you have does not work`*`, though being *Conditional* Formatting you do not normally need the IF. Please try selecting ColumnAA and in the formula rule:

```
  =AND(AA1<TODAY(),X1<>"Delivered",AA1<>"")
```

`*` I think your Applies to range may not have suited where you entered the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the $ anchor to be safe. The IF is not necessary. I just confirmed this soluton in Excel.

```
=AND(AA2 < TODAY(), X2 <>"Delivered")
```

Alternatively, you could try this. Sometimes rounding is required for date match comparisons due to the way Excel stores date values.

```
=AND(ROUND(AA2,5) < ROUND(TODAY(),5), X2 <>"Delivered")
```